# TextInputLayout hint position wrong

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I'm trying to manage the hint in a TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText, moving it inside a rounded shape, but I can't manage to move it, like in the picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMgH4.png)

This is my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

    module : app

    folder : layout

-->

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_activity_setting"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="it.numera.pagopaliteapp.activity.SettingActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorLayoutPagoBperBackgroundGenerale"
    >

    <!-- inizio sezione principale -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorLayoutPagoBperBackgroundGenerale"
    >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_activity_setting"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/rettangolo_smussato"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorLayoutPagoBperBackgroundGenerale"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_pagppa_55x35" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_setting_layout_email_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_activity_setting"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layoutpagobper_margin_from_toolbar"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_setting_label_email_default"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutpagobper_edittext_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_bold"
                android:text="@string/activity_setting_label_email_notifica_default"
                android:textColor="#005157"
                android:textSize="@dimen/layoutpagobper_font_size_testi_label_default"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_setting_edittext_email_default"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutpagobper_edittext_width"
                    android:layout_height="53dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
                    android:textColor="#005157"
                    android:textColorHint="#58979A"
                    android:background="@drawable/layoutpagobper_rettangolo_edittext_no_icon"
                    android:hint="@string/edittext_email_hint15" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_setting_label_info_email_default"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutpagobper_edittext_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
                android:text="Puoi modificare la tua email o cliccare il Conferma ed andare avanti"
                android:textColor="#005157"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_setting_layout_image_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layoutpagobper_margin_left"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/layoutpagobper_margin_right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity_setting_layout_email_default"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layoutpagobper_margin_from_bottom_screen"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_setting_imageButton_conferma"
                style="@style/OrangeButtonBperStyle"
                android:background="@drawable/layoutpagobper_rettangolo_background_imagebutton_orange"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_semibold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_setting_imageButton_back"
                style="@style/BlueButtonLinkBperStyle"
                android:background="@color/colorLayoutPagoBperButtonLabel"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_semibold"
                android:text="Homepage"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- inizio sezione navigation drawer -->
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer_layout"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is the rounded shape xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
                android:radius="0.8dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#58979A"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks

I've tried to change shape size, or the layout_margin of the TextInputEditText, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                   android:hint="@string/edittext_email_hint15"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_setting_edittext_email_default"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutpagobper_edittext_width"
                    android:layout_height="53dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
                    android:textColor="#005157"
                    android:textColorHint="#58979A"
                    android:background="@drawable/layoutpagobper_rettangolo_edittext_no_icon" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Apart From

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/activity_setting_edittext_email_default"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/layoutpagobper_edittext_width"
                    android:layout_height="53dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
                    android:textColor="#005157"
                    android:textColorHint="#58979A"                    
                   android:hint="@string/edittext_email_hint15"
android:background="@drawable/layoutpagobper_rettangolo_edittext_no_icon" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I changed the TextInputLayout, adding :

```
app:placeholderText="Il tuo indirizzo email"
```

instead of the `android:hint`, and now it works better.